# Gravação de Logs em linux

Tags: php, linux

Tenho o seguinte codigo em php

```
<?php
function logs($texto){
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $hora = date("H:i:s");
    $data = date("d-m-Y");
    $log = fopen("log/".$data.".txt","a+");
    $escreve = fwrite($log,$hora." - ".$texto. "\r\n");
    fclose($log);
}
?>
```

Fiz o teste nele em ambiente windows, funciona perfeitamente, entretanto quando passo para o linux, o mesmo para de gravar os logs, não cria nem o documento.
Tem que ter alguma permissão para tal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando o arquivo não pode ser escrito por motivos de permissão o php enviara um Warning. O que pode estar acontecendo é o php não tem permissão para escrever dentro do diretório "log". Uma solução seria usar o comando:

```
sudo chmod +777 log
```

Isso fara com que qualquer usuário tenha permissão total no diretório log. Ou utilizar o mesmo usuário do apache criar o diretório, dessa forma ele já tera permissão pra modificar os arquivos.

Comment: a permissão que tenho no diretorio é esta drwxr-xr-x, em teoria ele deveria deixar eu criar um novo arquivo e edita-lo não?

Comment: Não, você precisa ter permissão de write no diretório, diferente de como você mandou só tem permissão de read e execute.

Comment: ah, certo, irei tentar aqui. Obrigado

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Obrigado!!